# Php retorna JSON nulo quando tem acento no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, codificação-de-caracteres

Olá, tenho o seguinte código em php:

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","senha","banco");
   $parametro = $_GET["parametro"];
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysqli_connect_error(); }
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $parametro;

   if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
   {
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Ele retorna um JSON com uma tabela do servidor MySQL  cujo o nome foi passada pelo parametro, mas quando tem um acento ou um "ç" por exemplo ele retorna `null`
O MySQL esta aceitando a acentuação, posso checar isso pelo phpmyadmin, o problema mesmo esta no php.
Para uma tabela cidades ele retorna isso:

`[{"id":"1","nome":"Porto Alegre","estado":"RS"},{"id":"2","nome":"Rio de janeiro","estado":"RJ"},{"id":"3","nome":null,"estado":"SP"}]`

Onde deveria ser São Paulo ele retorna `null`

já tentei utiliza o json_encode com a constante JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE para codificar literalmente os caracteres em vez de escapa-los.

`echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

mas aparece esse erro: `Warning: json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/diretorio/public_html/busca.php on line 24`

como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução mais simples encontrada é adicionar essas duas linhas:

```
$str = str_replace('\u','u',$decoded);
$strJSON = preg_replace('/u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $str);
```

Fique atento à sua versão PHP, pois uso 5.5 e nos testes não tive este problema! Meus testes deram assim:

```
echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

> [{"id":"1","nome":"Porto Alegre","estado":"RS"},{"id":"2","nome":"Rio
>   de janeiro","estado":"RJ"},{"id":"3","nome":"SÃ£o
>   Paulo","estado":"SP"}]

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

> [{"id":"1","nome":"Porto Alegre","estado":"RS"},{"id":"2","nome":"Rio
>   de janeiro","estado":"RJ"},{"id":"3","nome":"S\u00e3o
>   Paulo","estado":"SP"}]

Comment: Mas como transformo o "S\u00e3o Paulo" em "São Paulo"? coloquei `<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>` mas mesmo assim não deu @Jhonnyjks

Comment: Cara, o melhor seria atualizar seu php para pelo menos 5.4.0, que assim ele aceitará o parâmetro JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, ou você deverá achar alguma função que decodifique de utf8, mas as convencionais não deram certo aqui.

Comment: Essas duas linhas resolveram agora: 

$str     = str_replace('\u','u',$decoded);
$strJSON = preg_replace('/u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $str);

Encontrei em: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20181671/5664531

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta algo assim:

```
<?php
       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","senha","banco");
       $parametro = $_GET["parametro"];
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysqli_connect_error(); }
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $parametro;

       if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
       {

        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            foreach($row as $key => $col){
               $col_array[$key] = utf8_encode($col);
            }
            $row_array[] =  $col_array;

        }
        echo json_encode($row_array);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, você pode usar a função mb_convert_encoding para converter o encoding

//Neste caso, assumindo que o padrão esteja em ISO-8859-1 e você quer UTF-8
mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');

Comment: Eu preciso implementar essa função em algum lugar especifico? pq fiz uns testes aqui e ainda resultou em `null` @Duque

Comment: Essa é uma função interna do PHP, ela parte do principio que você sabe a codificação que está a string.
Qual o padrão de codificação que está os dados da tabela ?
Você pode testar também com mb_strtolower( $row, 'UTF-8');  para teste.
Faz ai e posta aqui de novo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma linha antes do `echo json_encode($resultArray)`, coloca isso:

```
$resultArray = array_map('utf8_encode', $resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de retornar você chama uma função para converter o array em utf-8

```
$result = converteArrayParaUtf8($result); //chama a função
return json_encode($result); //retorna
```

função:

```
function converteArrayParaUtf8($result){
    array_walk_recursive($result, function(&$item,$key){
         if (!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)) {
                $item = utf8_encode($item);
            }
    });
    return $result;
}
```