# problema com acentuacao no autocomplete jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, autocompletar

Estou com um problema de UTF-8 no meu código.
Tenho um `input text` com autocomplete (função do jquery) que funciona ok com resultados vindo do MySQL, mas quando uma palavra está com acento a letra acentuada aparece um ponto de interrogação(?).
Segue meu código:

> retornar_cliente_processo.php

```
<?php require_once("conexao/conexao.php"); ?>
<?php
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT clienteNome as value,clienteId as id FROM cliente WHERE clienteNome LIKE '%".$term."%' LIMIT 10";

 $consulta_tr = mysqli_query($conecta, $qstring);
    if(!$consulta_tr) {
        die("erro no banco1");
    }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_tr,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes(utf8_decode($row['value'])));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
?>
```

> funcao js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#clientes').autocomplete({
        source: 'php/retornar_cliente_processo.php',
        minLength: 1,   

          select: function(event, ui) {

            $('#clienteId').val(ui.item.id);
            $('.form-control').removeAttr("disabled");  
            $('#clientes').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#alteraNome').removeAttr("disabled");        
                 },
            }); }
```

> html

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="formCad">

      <input type="hidden" name="clienteId" id="clienteId" placeholder="ID">   

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="clienteNome" class="control-label">Nome do cliente</label>

                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="clienteNome" id="clientes"  class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do cliente" required>

                  </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: coloque no `head` do html `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: já coloquei mas nada mudou

Comment: Veja se essa resposta lhe ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120835/43292

Comment: nao ajudou :(((

Comment: Dá uma olhada no seu mysql, faz um select no banco mesmo para ver se os dados estão com o *encode* correto.

Comment: está tudo ok.. eu percebi que se eu mudo essa linha: $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes(utf8_decode($row['value']))); pra encode ele aparece uns caracteres estranhos.. e decode ele aparece um ponto de interrogacao

Answer (score 0):

resolvi meu problema alterando a linha

```
$row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes(utf8_decode($row['value'])));
```

para

```
$row['value']=stripslashes(utf8_encode($row['value']));
```

Answer (score 0):

percebi que você usa utf8-decode-encode
já pensou em alterar a linguagem do banco de dados
não sei se iria resolver mais fica bem melhor

OBS:

```
    $con =  mysqli_connect("localhost","meu_user","meu_password","meu_db");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

mysqli_set_charset é o msm com a orientação

ai ficaria sua linha:

```
$row['value']= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['value']]);
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php